# Error: Cannot convert 'char(*)[a]' to 'char(*)[2]'. I don't understand why there's an error

Tags: c, arrays, dev-c++

In the code below if instead of `a` I use a number it works fine. But if i use `a` it gives the following error:

`Cannot convert 'char(*)[a]' to 'char(*)[2]' for argument '2' to 'void displayNumbers(int, char(*)[2])'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void displayNumbers(int,char num[2][2]);
int main()
{
    int a=2;
    char num[a][a];// if i write 2 instead of a, it works fine!
    displayNumbers(a,num);
    return 0;
}

void displayNumbers(int a,char num[2][2])
{
    printf("%c\n",a+ num[1][1]);
}
```

Why does using `a` or `2` make a difference here? I have a feeling the reason may be trivial but it would be really great if someone helps. The IDE i am using is Dev C++.

Comment: First, why do you want to print `num` if you don't set it before ?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @YaatSuka thats not the issue. my program was actually differnt. to understand where i was going wrong i was simplifying it

Comment: @Harshil Dev C++

Comment: It compiles fine for me on Mac.

Comment: @EnriquePineda so is it some problem with the compiler?

Comment: @Soc hard to say from here. I saw in your earlier comment that you simplified the code for posting. Is the simplified code still generating the error?

Comment: @EnriquePineda the code in the question is the simplified one and yeah its showing the mentioned error

Comment: `void displayNumbers(int,char num[2][2]);` --> `void displayNumbers(int a,char (*num)[a]);` ?

Comment: You get the error because you're using the **C++** compiler to compile a **C** program.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Isn't C a subset of C++? I have always used C++ compilers for C programs but didn't know that

Comment: @Soc **C** isn't a subset of **C++**.

Comment: C is not a subset of C++.  The two languages share history and a common subset, but each has features that the other lacks.  Furthermore, there exist simple constructs that are valid in both languages but have different meaning in each.  It is therefore foolish to compile C code with a C++ compiler, unless it has been intentionally written with that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three primary problems.

First the declaration of `displayNumber` hard-codes `num[2][2]` defeating the purpose of using a *Variable Length Array* (the *variable* part of the name is at issue). While `num[2][2]` is valid, it is better written as `num[a][a]`, or best `(num*)[a]` (a pointer to an array of char [a])

Next, `num` is completely uninitialized. What do you expect to print? Attempt to read an uninitialized value invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Last, your format string in `printf ("%c\n", a + num[1][1]);` is suspect. The function name is `displayNumber`, yet you are attempting to print a *character*. Further, if the value is below `' '` (space, e.g. 0x20, 32), nothing will print, you would be in the *Non-Printiable* range. If you want to print the number, use the `"%d"` *format specifier*.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void displayNumbers (int a, char (*num)[a]);

int main (void) {

    int a=2;
    char num[a][a];

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            num[i][j] = i + j;

    displayNumbers (a, num);

    return 0;
}

void displayNumbers (int a, char (*num)[a])
{
    printf ("%d\n", a + num[1][1]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dispnum
4
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Example Compile and Use on TDM-GCC 4.9.2**

I have TDM-GCC 4.9.2 on a Win7 box. It works fine. Here is the version, compile and run on Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>gcc --version
gcc (tdm-1) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Ofast -std=gnu11 -o bin\dispnum dispnum.c

C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>bin\dispnum
4
```

(I left the full directory and path information as an example that you can compile from anywhere as long as `gcc.exe` is in your path)

Comment: Well, i had tried your code, still produces errors, it says 'a' and 'num' was not declared in this scope. I don't know why this error is coming. your code looks fine. Probably its some problem with the compiler

Comment: Wow. (if you copy and paste it and use a C-compiler that supports the VLA extension, I guarantee it will work -- without warning or error) How and what are you using to compile it? On gcc, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Ofast -o dispnum dispnum.c` or for VS use `cl.exe /Wall /Ox /Fedispnum /Tcdispnum.c`. I'll have to lookup the `clang` string if you need it.

Comment: i am using Dev C++, that is the problem i guess.

Comment: I think you are right, are you on windows or Linux? (you can download the free VS community with the command line compiler if you are) If you are on Linux, then `gcc` should be installed. I'll look at Dev C++ and see if I can find something out for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am on windows

Comment: C89 and C++ do not support VLAs (Variable Length Arrays). For C11 they are optional. @Soc

Comment: The website says it can be downloaded with `TDM-GCC 4.9.2` which is plain old `gcc` [**Dev-C++ Blog**](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/). There is something strange about what you are doing to compile it. You may have `std=c89` set which does not itself have VLA extensions. I really, really recommend just opening `cmd.exe` (making sure the path to the compiler is set in your `path` variable) and just using the command line to learn how to build small programs. Many times an IDE can hide things from you that will give you fits.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin okay

Comment: @Soc, if you do have `TDM-GCC` installed, then you can simply open `cmd.exe` and use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -o dispnum dispnum.c` It's not a bad compiler.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i have tdm-gcc 4.9.2 on dev c++

Comment: Then the best thing you can do for learning C (or any language) is forget the IDE for now, and just use `cmd.exe` to learn what compiler options you need. An IDE has reams of dialogs that set compiler options and many are not-so-obvious. Learning from the command line hides nothing from you and will give you a firm foundation on how the compiler actually works (you can then tell the IDE what you want it to do, instead of *hoping* it is doing the right thing). Just make sure `gcc.exe` is in your path (it's probably in something like `/program files/DevC++/MinGW/bin)`. Good luck.

Comment: @Soc, I updated the answer to show a compile on Windows 7 with TDM-GCC 4.9.2. See under **Example Compile and Use on TDM-GCC 4.9.2**. Good luck. You will get it all figured out shortly and it will become 2nd nature. (It's just a pain the first time `:)` As an editor, look at [**geany**](https://github.com/geany/geany/)